# Spring Security OAuth2 - optional login with server check

Tags: spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm working on a Web Project with different Spring Boot WebMVC Clients. Some of this Clients needs a authorization and I solved it with a Spring Security OAuth2 Server. The authentication works fine and I had no problems. Some Clients didn't need an login and they are public for all.

**Technical facts**: All clients use a mix between Angular, jQuery and simple JSP's. All apps use Spring Security and the public app configuration is like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

**Now my question**: I plan to build a Login (or Logout) Button in the Header of all apps. In the apps with a required authentication is that no problem. I can check the principal is null or not. But how can I solve this in public apps. The principal is ever null and the client didn't check the authentication status with the server. I had some ideas to fix it but nothing is working. The best way would be a automatic check in Spring Boot. But how can I configure this? Maybe I can check it with JavaScript, but my shots also didn't work.

Maybe it would help - two of my apps:

- https://www.planyourtrip.travel (public application)
- https://profile.planyourtrip.travel (memberonly application)

**UPDATE: Maybe a better example**

If I configure a public app like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

and the MVC Controller like this

```
@RequestMapping("/{([a-z]{2})}")
public ModelAndView start(final Principal principal) {
    return new ModelAndView("start");
}
```

then is the Principal ever null. I think that is my Problem. I need a check with the OAuth Server and if i logged in is the principal set and if I'm not logged in it should be null.

Answer (score 0):

If I had understood your question correctly, than you need that some URL pattern can be accessed without authentication. Than in that case you can use the following method to prevent authentication for certain URL patterns -

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/urlPattern");
}
```

**permitAll()** method defines that all the **authenticated** users can access mentioned URL pattern. So if you want some users to access some resources (URL) without authentication, than you have to use above method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't mean this. I haven't a problem with "can be accessed without authentication". That works fine with permitAll(). My problem is that the Principal is ever null with this solution. I need a optional check with the oauth Server: public ModelAndView start(final Principal principal)